# Mapping entities with same base class from different assembly with AUTOMAPPER

Tags: c#, nhibernate, automapper

I've different assemblies containing a set of classes I want to map with NHibernate Automapper.
I know all these classes inherit from the same BaseEntity class.

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work!

```
 var m =  AutoMap.Assemblies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
                typeof(BaseEntity).Assembly)
                .Where(IsDomainEntity)
                .OverrideAll(ShouldIgnoreProperty)
                .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<BaseEntity>()
                .IgnoreBase<BaseEntity>();
```

**Update**

I've a folder containing dll I load via Windsor Castle. One of those assembly contains one or more classes I want to map with NHibernate Automapper. I've no reference in my project points to those classes.

How can I configure Automapper to register them?

Comment: some more details would help a lot. expected and actual result, exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

```
AutoMap.Assemblies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
    typeof(BaseEntity).Assembly,
    Assembly.Load("dllContainingClassesToMap"))
```